# C# OR specification in IF statement

Tags: c#

If I have **IF** condition like:

```
if(x == 0 || y == 4)
{
// ...
}
```

then if `x == 0` is true does c# checks if `y == 4` while we already know the whole expression is **true**?

Comment: This can be answered by the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator). (_"If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand isn't evaluated"_)

Comment: Would it make a change if c# does it or not since you would go into the statement anyways?

Comment: @cataklysim yes, the code on the right could easily contain side effects. It could be a function call

Comment: Or you can check it by yourself, put `return 4` inside some method, compare `y` with that method, add breakpoint inside method and check if that hits.

Comment: @Cataklysim in my case I had to know

Comment: @SeM yee that's also a good idea thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool operands. **If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand isn't evaluated**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator

Answer (score -1):

Look at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator). So the answer is **NO**, it doesn't check

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool
>   operands. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand
>   isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second
>   operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to
>   true or false.

Comment: This answer was absolutely wrong before the edit...